# compute Jacobian a Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I have two Tensors U and V (are output  of tensorflow.SVD(tf.varaible(W)) and I want to calculate Jacobian of U, V ,but Tensor flow does not support Jacobian, I also  tried Gradient but the output is None
 Do you know how can I get Jacobian respect to a Tensor ?